# xfrac.sty not found

Tags: packages, texlive, xfrac

I am using Tex Live 2011 on Windows, and when I compile (vim-latex) my file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% makes for prettier typography
\usepackage{microtype}
% For slanted fractions e.g. 4/4
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
%\input{title.tex}

\include{main}
\end{document
```

I get the following error:

```
template.tex|| File `xfrac.sty' not found.
template.tex|8 error| Emergency stop.
template.tex|| ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can your TeX system find `xfrac.sty` if you leave off the `\usepackage(microtype}` instruction?

Comment: No, it still can't find it. In fact it installed both `amsmath` and `microtype` packages fine, but for some reason `xfrac` is giving it trouble.

Comment: If its not installed (for whatever reason), try `tlmgr install --reinstall xfrac` from your command prompt.

Comment: That gives me the error `tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
package xfrac not present in package repository.`

Comment: @drozzy: Then try Boris' suggestion using `tlmgr install --reinstall l3packages`.

Comment: @drozzy I believe you should read about how to update and maintain your TeX installs. How it works. This thread has gone into a dead-spin of trial and error. See MikTeX: [Maintenance](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/configuring.html), [Update](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/updating.html), [Install packages](http://docs.miktex.org/2.9/manual/pkgmgt.html). Under TeXlive you should look up: [Update](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install__option_____pkg___) and in [TeXlive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html) under the options that have been suggested by users on this page

Answer (score 7):

The command `tlmgr search --file xfrac.sty` says that `xfrac.sty` is installed by the package `l3packages`.  So installing this package from `tlmgr` interface (or updating it if you have an old version) will install this file.

Comment: Wow, I don't even know what this `tlmgr` thing is... Anyways I tried `tlmgr update --self` and then `tlmgr install l3packages`, but no cigar. I get the same error: `xfrac.sty` not found.

Comment: Try `tlmgr update --all`

Comment: Will try that at work. What about if I don't use Tex Live - but only Mike Tex (like I do at home): there is no tlmgr command...

Comment: @drozzy MikTeX installs missing packages "on the fly" during compilation, so it should take care of this issue for you automagically.

Comment: @Sharpie It says the same thing `xfrac.sty` not found etc... I don't understand why they had to move things around? Do they have a special committee on "how to confuse people"? PS: I am using `nicefrac` in the meantime - while I try to fix this issue...

Answer (score 5):

According to the file datestamps on the CTAN, the `xfrac` package was last updated on 12/29/2011. I suppose it's possible that if you ran `tlmgr update --all` since then, something migh have gone wrong in the update process without you noticing.

Try running

```
tlmgr install --reinstall xfrac
```

from the command line and see if this brings the needed relief. You may have to be in the directory `c:\texlive\2011\bin\win32` (or wherever `tlmgr.bat` is located on your Windows system).

**Addendum**: I see from your comment that your current CTAN repository is `ctan.cms.math.ca`. For what it's worth, the `xfrac` package seems to be available at the CTAN mirror site `mirrors.med.harvard.edu` (and probably many other CTAN mirror sites too). You might want to try running the command

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

or

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirrors.med.harvard.edu/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

from the command line (to reset tlmgr's default CTAN repository information) before (re)running the `tlmgr install ...` command I suggested earlier.

Comment: `tlmgr: package repository http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
package xfrac not present in package repository.`