# Define my own xfrac command?

Tags: macros, fractions, xfrac

Is it possible to create my own xfrac command - without using that package (it is giving me [too much trouble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41044/xfrac-sty-not-found))? I know you can do superscript, subscript to make a fraction look.

Can I do something like:

```
 \newcommand xfrac{a}{b} = ^a/_b
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problems you describe in the other question are still not resolved, and if they are it will make it a lot easier! I encourage you to stay on that path of resolution!

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I have a pressing deadline, so I need to find a way that works now :-( I will try to resolve the other problem when I get more time.

Comment: Related Question: [How to make fractions in powers look good](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202325/how-to-make-fractions-in-powers-look-good).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider to use the [`nicefrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) package. It was last updated in 1998, so it shouldn't cause *"too much trouble"*. For its drawbacks see section 1.2 of the `xfrac` (sic!) documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\nicefrac{1}{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Here is the best I could come up with. You might need to adjust the parameters below as I have only tested it for this one case. The output on the left is the one from the macro below, and the output of `\sfrac` from [the `xfrac` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) is on the right. These two look pretty much identical to me:

[image]

This is adapted from what you posted with `\kern` being used to move the numbers closer to the slash, and `\raisebox` from [the `\graphicx` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) used to more the numbers into the same vertical position as the produced by `\sfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\newcommand*{\myxfrac}[2]{\raisebox{-0.33ex}{${}^{#1}$\kern-0.1em}/\kern-0.1em{{\raisebox{0.34ex}{$_{#2}$}}}}%

\begin{document}
\[
    \myxfrac{1}{2}  \quad \sfrac{1}{2}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But, please do consider what zeroth commented:  You should figure out how to install the package and get to the bottom of why it is missing in your install.  This might be an indication of other things that might also be broken.

Comment: Maybe I'm just dumb and I would love to figure it out - but when I have to finish my project, and the thing does not work after two days of troubleshooting, I gotta draw a line somewhere!

Comment: Yep, that makes sense if you are the late stages of a project...

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid an extra package, you can could use the definition below as well. It now has taken [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)'s comment from below into account.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\makeatletter
\def\nicefrac#1#2{\check@mathfonts%
  \raise.5ex\hbox{\the\scriptfont0 #1}%
  \kern-.1em/\kern-.15em%
  \lower.25ex\hbox{\the\scriptfont0 #2}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
Here is a nice in-line fraction: $\nicefrac{21}{234}$.
\end{document}
```

To give proper credit: I believe I found the definition once in a book by Knuth. It's living in my pile of TeX snippets that I search for occasions like this. You could rename it to `\xfrac` in the definition or use `\let\xfrac\nicefrac` to make it available under both names.

[image: fraction]

Comment: In order to use it also outside math-mode, one should do also `\check@mathfonts`, otherwise `\scriptfont0` might be undefined or wrong. If you plan to use it only in math mode, then `\leavevmode` is redundant.