# How to increase row height while using booktabs?

Tags: tables, spacing, fractions, booktabs

I'm making a table using booktabs. One of the columns contains a series of fractions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
    \usepackage{nag}
    \usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{3}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This is what is looks like:

[image: table]

The height of each row is just a tad too small -- the fractions are uncomfortably squished. Is there any way I can increase the row height so the fractions fit more comfortably?

If possible, I'd also like to avoid making any changes to other tables that I might add to my document.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For single lines `booktabs` provides `\addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{lrc} 
\toprule[2pt]
a & b & c \\ 
\cmidrule[1pt](rl){1-3}
d & e & f \\ 
j & k & l \\ 
\addlinespace[0.5em]
g & h & i \\ 
\bottomrule[2pt] 
\end{tabular}\caption{abcde}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot taken from Beamer document]

Comment: Though your output more looks like `beamer` (no Table number, sans serif font) and you definetly defined a german package - the `addlinespace` is the “right” way to do it, which is provided by `booktabs`

Answer (score 21):

The easiest here would be to adjust the value of `\arraystretch`. For example,

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
```

Here's a view on the difference:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
%\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{3}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \mytable
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
  \mytable
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that this affects the entire table. For more (including individual modifications), see [Column padding in tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Comment: I don't recommend this since `\arraystretch` in conjunction with `booktabs` breaks the symmetry as you can clearly see above!

Answer (score 16):

This might seem complicated, but allows for fine tuning the output: since fractions are the culprits in this particular situation and changing `\arraystretch` would affect all table rows, I propose to use a different command for the fractions, so as to insert a strut next to them; this strut is larger than the normal one and computed from the fractions themselves.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\newcommand{\fracpadding}{}
\newcommand{\setfracpadding}[1][2pt]{%
  \sbox0{$\frac{1}{2}$}%
  \dimen0=\ht0 \advance\dimen0 #1\relax
  \dimen2=\dp0 \advance\dimen2 #1\relax
  \edef\fracpadding{\vrule width 0pt height \the\dimen0 depth \the\dimen2\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\afrac}[2]{\fracpadding\frac{#1}{#2}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\setfracpadding
\caption{Test}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
A: $\afrac{6}{16}$ B: $\afrac{5}{16}$ C: $\afrac{3}{16}$ D: $\afrac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
A: $\afrac{6}{16}$ B: $\afrac{5}{16}$ C: $\afrac{4}{16}$ D: $\afrac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
A: $\afrac{6}{16}$ B: $\afrac{6}{16}$ C: $\afrac{2}{16}$ D: $\afrac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
A: $\afrac{6}{16}$ B: $\afrac{6}{16}$ C: $\afrac{3}{16}$ D: $\afrac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
A: $\afrac{7}{16}$ B: $\afrac{3}{16}$ C: $\afrac{3}{16}$ D: $\afrac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
A: $\afrac{7}{16}$ B: $\afrac{4}{16}$ C: $\afrac{3}{16}$ D: $\afrac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
A: $\afrac{7}{16}$ B: $\afrac{4}{16}$ C: $\afrac{4}{16}$ D: $\afrac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
A: $\afrac{7}{16}$ B: $\afrac{5}{16}$ C: $\afrac{2}{16}$ D: $\afrac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
A: $\afrac{7}{16}$ B: $\afrac{5}{16}$ C: $\afrac{3}{16}$ D: $\afrac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The default padding is 2pt above and below the fraction; one can also say `\setfracpadding[3pt]` or with another length. Instead of setting it globally, I suggest to set it where needed; so if you change your mind and decide to typeset a table with such fractions in smaller type, you can simply add the `\small` or `\footnotesize` declaration just before `\setfracpadding`.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I'd avoid the problem by using slightly smaller in-line fractions with `\nfrac{7}{16}`. See also [how to define `\xfrac`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41179/define-my-own-xfrac-command/41181#41181), another macro (and package) for in-line fractions.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs

\makeatletter
\def\nfrac#1#2{\check@mathfonts%
    \raise.5ex\hbox{\the\scriptfont0 #1}%
    \kern-.1em/\kern-.15em%
    \lower.25ex\hbox{\the\scriptfont0 #2}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\mytable}{%
  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    A: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{5}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    A: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{5}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{4}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    A: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    A: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{6}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    A: $\nfrac{7}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    A: $\nfrac{7}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{4}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    A: $\nfrac{7}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{4}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{4}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    A: $\nfrac{7}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{5}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    A: $\nfrac{7}{16}$ B: $\nfrac{5}{16}$ C: $\nfrac{3}{16}$ D: $\nfrac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{\strut Test}
  \mytable
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table using \nfrac]

Answer (score 5):

This is not a robust way of doing what you want but just a rusty hack:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
%\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\newcommand{\vhtable}{\rule{0pt}{15pt}}% defines the separation and can be different if you so desire for each different row.
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    \vhtable A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{3}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    \vhtable A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the height of the rule, that is, change `15pt` to whatever you feel should be the right height separation.

Comment: this would be a bit nicer if the rule had its extent divided between height and depth.  there's a bit more space than needed above the first row, and not enough after the last row.  some experimentation is probably necessary, but i'd start at 10pt above and 5 below to keep the total 15 used in the example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree. Will edit as soon as I have some time or if you can add it in, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Whereas I would advice to `arraystretch` as in Werners answer, you can use the following macro `TabV`  to make vertical room around a table entry. It's handy if you don't want to increase the spacing for all lines.

In the following example only the second and 6th line got more vertical space:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\newcommand*{\TabV}[1]{%
  \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\fbox{\hspace*{-\fboxsep}#1\hspace*{-\fboxsep}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    A: \TabV{$\frac{6}{16}$} B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{3}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: \TabV{$\frac{4}{16}$} C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: there is default `rowsep=2pt` in `tblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{nag}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Test}
\begin{tblr}{llll}
    \toprule
    A & B & C & D \\
    \midrule
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.9375919592 & 1.88285606369 & 0.0547358955059 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.94014431443 & 1.80503653258 & 0.135107781856 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.87649654966 & 1.81127812446 & 0.0652184251977 \\
    A: $\frac{6}{16}$ B: $\frac{6}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87992559246 & 1.76409765557 & 0.115827936888 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{3}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{3}{16}$ & 1.93245604561 & 1.88024081494 & 0.0522152306624 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.86806360636 & 1.84960175271 & 0.0184618536479 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{4}{16}$ C: $\frac{4}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.87194209421 & 1.7717822216 & 0.100159872612 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{2}{16}$ D: $\frac{2}{16}$ & 1.81500630063 & 1.79617969195 & 0.0188266086843 \\
    A: $\frac{7}{16}$ B: $\frac{5}{16}$ C: $\frac{3}{16}$ D: $\frac{1}{16}$ & 1.81178637864 & 1.74899922306 & 0.0627871555774 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]