# Increase vertical row spacing in booktabs, but keep content vertically centered

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularx

I am using tabularx + booktabs and I am looking for a way to increase the vertical spacing between rows, but at the same time keep the content of each row vertically centered.

I have tried to use `arraystretch` but, as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80076/78415), the additional space is not evenly distributed; more space tends to be added to the 'top' of the row than to the bottom.

I would like to find a solution that affects all rows in all tables of a document (which has dozens of long tables) without having to manually insert spaces, struts, etc. for each individual row.

More details: I am not using midrules to separate individual rows. I am relying on `\rowcolor` to differentiate rows.

Here's a MWE taken from [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340401/78415):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\toprule
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\

1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\toprule
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\

1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`. Unfortunately, when applied to the `X` column type and `colortbl is loaded, it doesn't work any more, for some reason.

So I had to use a work-around: `cellspace` is used for the first column, and at the end of an `X` cell, I automatically add an invisible rule under the base line with `>{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{1.5ex}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{1.5ex}
\rowcolors{2}{lightgray!30!Lavender}{white}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Sl l X <{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{0ex}}}%
\toprule
\rowcolor{white}
A & B &\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\ %
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\ %
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works very well. But I didn't need the invisible rule workaround at all. What problem is it fixing ?

Comment: It replaces  `\addlinespace` and adds some padding under the last line of the `X` cells. If you don't have it, normally the coloured zone ends very close (too close in my opinion) below the last line.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Indeed this fixes it.

Comment: It doesn't work with X columns also when colortbl is not used.

Comment: @yannis: Could you post as anew question a small illustrating the problems you meet?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you could be helped if there was a `\extrarowdepth` parameter similar to `\extrarowheight`. The package `tabu` has that. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with multiline cells. So I wrote a small package that does just that: add an `\extrarowdepth` parameter.

It works even when `tabu` is loaded, but not for the `tabu` environment. It just shares the its `\extrarowdepth` length parameter in that case, just to avoid a conflict.

Here it is:

```
%% extrarowdepth.sty
%% Copyright (C) 2016 by Piet van Oostrum <piet@vanoostrum.org>
%% This package defines a new length variable \extrarowdepth, similar to
%% \extrarowheight in the `array' package.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{extrarowdepth}%
           [2016/11/225 v1.0 Define \string\extrarowdepth\space for arrays and tabulars]%
% Prevent a clash with tabu, or other packages that also define \extrarowdepth.
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifdefdimen\extrarowdepth{} % \extrarowdepth already defined as a length
  {\ifdef\extrarowdepth % if it is defined but not a length, we have an error
    {\PackageError{extrarowdepth}{Cannot define length \string\extrarowdepth}
      {There is already a \string\extrarowdepth\space and it is not a length parameter.}}
    {\newlength\extrarowdepth\setlength\extrarowdepth{0pt}}}%
  \newlength\@temprowdepth}

\RequirePackage{array}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\@array}{\setbox \@arstrutbox \hbox{\vrule \@height \arraystretch \@tempdima \@depth \arraystretch \dp \strutbox \@width \z@}}
{\@temprowdepth  \dp \strutbox \advance \@temprowdepth by\extrarowdepth \setbox \@arstrutbox \hbox{\vrule \@height \arraystretch \@tempdima \@depth \arraystretch \@temprowdepth \@width \z@}}
{\PackageInfo{extrarowdepth}{\string\extrarowdepth\space added to the array package}}
{\PackageWarning{extrarowdepth}{Failed to include \string\extrarowdepth\space in the array package}}
\let\@@array\@array
```

And here is an example how to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{extrarowdepth}

\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{lightgray!30!Lavender}{white}

\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}
\setlength\extrarowdepth{4pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\toprule
\rowcolor{white}
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is great :) It would be nice if the extrarowdepth could be defiend in the preamble, though; right now it must be defined after begin{document}

Comment: Well, if you promise not to use the tabu package, or use it before extrarowdepth, you can take out the \AtBeginDocument part. I just want to prevent a clash if tabu comes after extrarowdepth. I'll think about it.

Comment: And if you don't use tabu, you can add in the preamble: `\newlength\extrarowdepth \setlength\extrarowdepth{...}` and the package will be happy at `\begin{document}` to see that the length is already there.

Answer (score 1):

Act on the parameters `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\toprule
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\setlength{\aboverulesep}{10pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{10pt}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
\toprule
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With colored rows, you can insert `\addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{white}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{llX}
\toprule
\rowcolor{white}
A & B & \centering C \tabularnewline
\midrule
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\ \addlinespace
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\ \addlinespace
1 & 2 & \lipsum*[2] \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good one (+1), it almost does what I need. My only problem is that I am not actually using midrules between regular table rows -- I am relying on `\rowcolors` to differentiate rows. This introduces two problems: 1/ aboverulesep and belowrulesep don't help if there are no rules, 2/ the spacing introduced by these commands doesn't get allong well with row coloring. I'll update my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Grodriguez Row coloring and `booktabs` don't go along anyway.

Comment: Why? It seems to work pretty well so far

Comment: `\addlinespace` -- yes, that's what I was trying to avoid (as this means I need to modify each individual line of each table). Or is it possible to globally redefine `\tabularnewline` (which I am using everywhere) to automatically call `\addlinespace` ?

Comment: @Grodriguez No, as you also want to cope with rules.