# How to make fractions in powers look good

Tags: pdftex, fractions, displaystyle

Quick question. When I type `$e^{\frac{1}{2x}}$` it makes the fraction very small and hard to read. However when I type `$e^{\displaystyle\frac{1}{2x}}$` it makes the fraction way to big. I guess in either case they do not look good to me. Is there a nice way to make fractions in powers look good?

Comment: The `nicefrac`package might help as well: `$e^{\nicefrac{1}{2}}$`

Comment: Related Question: [Define my own xfrac command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41179/define-my-own-xfrac-command).

Comment: Use inline notation: `$e^{1/2x}$` or `$\exp(1/2x)$`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/how-do-i-typeset-arbitrary-fractions-like-the-standard-symbol-for-5-%C2%BD

Comment: I am surprised that nobody mentioned `tfrac`.

Answer (score 35):

You can also use the `xfrac` package which provides `\sfrac` which works in text and math mode:

[image]

### Note:

- I stopped using `\sfrac` when I realized that it was resulting in really slow compiles when used in conjunction with [the `microtype` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/microtype)  as per:

  - [Why does the use of microtype and xfrac lead to a long compile time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27963/why-does-the-use-of-microtype-and-xfrac-lead-to-a-long-compile-time)
  - [Disable microtype for a portion of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/disable-microtype-for-a-portion-of-a-document)

  I think these problems are supposed to have been fixed with `microtype` v2.5, but in case you encounter really slow compile times you may want to try it without the `microtype` package or without `\sfrac{}`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
Works in text mode \sfrac{1}{2} and in math mode $\sfrac{1}{2}$.

In exponents: $e^{\sfrac{1}{2}}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 20):

Your question was:

> While in text mode (aka inline math mode), how does one make fractions in powers look good?

A very important objective in fine typography is to keep the "color" -- really, the "average grayness" -- of paragraphs uniform within a page and across pages. One important aspect of "color" is the line spacing and, in particular, its uniformity: If interline spacing varies noticeably within a paragraph and across paragraphs, "color" is jeopardized and the document is going to look awful, at least from a typographic standpoint.

Unless you have something like `doublespacing` in place (and have therefore ruined the look of the paragraph anyway), having math terms with fractional exponents inside running text requires TeX to insert a considerable amount of extra vertical whitespace relative to the preceding line, ruining the paragraph's color. That's a good reason for trying to avoid using any terms in subscript and superscript positions that force TeX to insert extra interline spacing, right? In the *TeXbook*, Knuth recommends using *inline-style fractional expressions*, e.g., `$1/2$` instead of `\frac{1}{2}`, for just this situation.

As you've noted, writing `$e^{\frac{1}{2x}}$` renders the material in the numerator and denominator in `scriptscriptstyle` (50% linear reduction from `textstyle`), which makes it potentially hard to decipher. Some potential fixes:

- Using inline fractional math notation, i.e., writing `$e^{1/2x}$`, renders the material in the exponent in `scriptstyle` (30% linear reduction from `textstyle`), which should be no problem for legibility.
- The `\nicefrac` macro (provided by the `nicefrac` package), when used in an exponent, makes the fractional term look a lot less cramped than if `\frac` were used; however, it also renders the numerator and denominator in `scriptscriptstyle`, re-raising the issue of basic legibility.
- If the term in the exponent is too complicated to be displayed easily in superscript position, consider typing `$\exp(\sfrac{1}{2x})$`. (The `\nicefrac` and `\sfrac` macros typeset their argument very similarly, by the way.)

In the following screenshot, the `\dfrac` solution is shown mostly to illustrate what should not be done *under any circumstance*. My personal preference would be for either the third or the fifth solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}    % for \xfrac macro
\usepackage{nicefrac} % for \nicefrac macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \dfrac macro
\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}

\begin{document}
some words $\e^{\frac{1}{2x}}$ $\e^{\dfrac{1}{2x}}$ $\e^{1/2x}$ 
$\e^{\nicefrac{1}{2x}}$ $\exp(\sfrac{1}{2x})$ some more words
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15):

Here are the variants to choose

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nice]{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
  $e^{1/2}$ $e^{(1/2)}$ $e^{0.5}$

  With \verb|nicefrac|

    $e^{\nicefrac{1}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `ugly` option to `nicefrac`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ugly]{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
  With \verb|nicefrac|

    $e^{\nicefrac{1}{2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]