# Avoid italicizing text inside math inside theorem-like environments

Tags: math-mode, formatting, theorems, italic

I strongly suspect this is a duplicate but just could not find it answered.

Specific example: I need a 1/2 in subscripts and I use `_{\text\textonehalf}` for that purpose (`\textonehalf` is from the `textcomp` package). But inside theorems it becomes italicized, which I would like to avoid.

Is there a canonical way to handle this?

Here is a mwe

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{Theorem}
Theorem-like environments make $x_{\text\textonehalf}$ look ugly.
\end{Theorem}

\begin{proof}
Look how cool does it look outside of them: $x_{\text\textonehalf}$!
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\text` explicitly asks for the outer text font, perhaps `\textup` is what you are looking for.

Comment: and now you know why `\text` is the wrong command to use. (there are so many users who apply `\text` as a big hammer to solve every problem)

Comment: @daleif I am curious to know what you mean, but I cannot tell at all from what you wrote. Is there a better way to get text into math environments than \text?

Comment: As David mentions `\text` is the wrong command to use. Here you want the subscript to always be upright. But that is not what `\text` does. It typeset its contents in the font front outside math. In the theorem, the font outside math is italics and thus the output of `\text` is italics. Do you see my point. As I also mention you're not the first person to do this mistake. IMO this misuse is one of the most common

Comment: Okay, you just mean \text is the wrong tool here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are looking for some way to make subscript fractions look nice.
Therefor I would suggest using the nicefrac package and/or xfrac package.

You can find some explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202325/how-to-make-fractions-in-powers-look-good)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}


\begin{Theorem}
Theorem-like environments make $x_{\sfrac{1}{2}}$ look awesome with another package.
\end{Theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! The solution you propose is entirely satisfactory. It is worth accepting, I am just waiting - maybe somebody proposes something which works more generally for any kind of text-inside-math, as in a comment by @DavidCarlisle above